# Redrawing clipped content in Android View after moving into bounds

Tags: android, android-layout, clipping

Within Android, I'm trying to move a `TextView` from outside the parents bounds into view, but the contents never shows up, or remains clipped if it was partially within the bounds already.

**Initial situation at start**
 [image]

**Situation after animation**
 [image]

*(Below this is another view, that was completely out of bounds and isn't drawn either)*

I have 4 `TextViews` below each other in a custom Object extending `RelativeLayout`. Based on a percentage the top 2 should move outside it's bounds and the bottom 2 should move in (from the bottom).

I use the following code to update the properties of each `TextView`. In this class each variable **positionY* is filled with their initial position from the layout-xml. *effect* is percentage between 0 & 1. The animation works, but the views aren't drawn again.

```
public class ActionBarTitleView extends RelativeLayout {
    public void updateTransition(float effect) {
        float height = getHeight();
        titleView1.setY(title1positionY - height*effect);
        detailView1.setY(detail1positionY - height*effect);
        titleView2.setY(title2positionY - height*effect);
        detailView2.setY(detail2positionY - height*effect);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

**What I tried**

After some researching I found a few hints what the issue might be, but so far none of the tried options had any effect. Below is a list of things I've found on SO and tried.

Calling invalidate() on the RelativeLayout - No effect.
Invalditing the TextViews - No effect.
clipChildren = false for the RelativeLayout - No effect.
setWillNotDraw = false for the RelativeLayout - No effect. (onDraw is being called)

I haven't tried to solve this with a ScrollView, but I don't want to really, cause that adds another layer in the hierachy for something pretty small.

I thought I understood the drawing logic, but perhaps I'm missing something, so I hope someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

**What I ended up doing (September 3rd)**

Since no real solution was offered, I tried again and came to the following "fix". I set both second labels to Visibility.GONE, but within the original bounds of the container view. Then when I start the animation, I set their correct values, then move them outside the bounds and finally setting Visiblity.VISIBLE. When the animation progresses the labels roll into view as supposed to. So a fix to the issue, but no real explanation why the TextViews aren't drawn again...

Comment: Textviews are clipped differently than all other views, they are clipped in onDraw and the part the view calculates as outside is never drawn. You need to make the believe it's ok for it to draw where you want it to.

Comment: Thank you @JohanShogun for pointing me to this. I tried to find something on TextView that could work for me, but I'm not sure what to use here. Should I be subclassing TextView and override onDraw to do something?

The issue is not that I want to draw stuff outside of the container bounds. I rather want to redraw it's children, at their actual position after those position have been updated. The drawing is as expected really, it just needs to update after children views have moved.